# Should HttpUrl.Builder.addPathSegment %2A encode an asterisk?

Tags: okhttp

I'm curious why this passes.. eg the asterisk below isn't percent encoded as %2A.

```
HttpUrl url = new HttpUrl.Builder()
    .scheme("http")
    .host("host")
    .addPathSegment("foo *")
    .build();
assertEquals("http://host/foo%20*", url.toString());
assertEquals("/foo%20*", url.encodedPath());
```

Comment: cross-linking here: https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/3488

Answer (score -1):

Major browsers (Firefox, Safari, and Chrome) choose not to percent encode * as %20 when it is in the path segment, and therefore OkHttp chooses to be consistent with those behaviors.

The only part of a URL that the browsers and OkHttp differ on for * is the host in which Safari and OkHttp will error, Firefox leaves as is, and Chrome percent encodes as %20.

[Research](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BgGAhJ5WE3JBsATeudamiBzxmgEhwkfcFqQmPx8qrkc/edit#gid=0), [Github](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/3488),
[Blog Post](https://publicobject.com/2017/08/01/url-encoding-is-material/)

Comment: Can you add some context around your links? Remember links are great (and often required for attribution), but your answer should be still be valid and if in the future the links become dead. Good luck!

Comment: For instance, you mention that _Research Shows_, can you add maybe a quick run down of what research was done? What the basic outcome was? That would go very far in turning this into a great answer :)

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)